# VB.NET - Error Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference (WindowsIdentity.Groups Property)

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, windows-identity, active-directory-group

I am getting the following error:

```
   Error    1   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.  
                (on WindowsIdentity.Groups)
```

Here's my code from that uses the [WindowsIdentity.Groups property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.groups.aspx) to display the identity references for the groups the current user belongs to. This code is part of a larger example provided for the [WindowsIdentity class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx).

```
    Public ReadOnly Property Groups As IdentityReferenceCollection
    Get
        Dim irc As IdentityReferenceCollection
        Dim ir As IdentityReference

        irc = WindowsIdentity.Groups
        For Each ir In irc
            MsgBox(ir.Value)
        Next

    End Get
    End Property
```

I tried fixing this error by putting:

```
    Dim myWindowsIdentity As New WindowsIdentity
```

but got the following error:

```
    Error   2   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts 
                this number of arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either have the object, or you must create a new one (which you did).  The second error is because you haven't provided any arguments for the constructors (new).  If you are using Visual Studio, it should have intellisense.  Put a ( after "as new WindowsIdentity" and check to see what arguments are required.

Comment: I'm not sure what to put, there are 7 options provided by intellisense

Comment: Provide it with the arguments that best match the purposes of what you are trying to perform.  If you can't figure it out.  Google the object.

Comment: Uhhhhh "google it" is not a helpful answer haha. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the topic that you are now asking.  I answered the actual question.  I don't know what you are making, how would I know what arguments you need to pass?